# Q: How to create multi auth user profiles in Laravel 7

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

I am working on a new project, and so far I have managed to get multi auth working. But now I am trying to find a way to create and associate a Profile for both type of auth in my case Applicants and Employers right from the RegisterController.

It might be simple for some of you but all new to PHP and laravel.

```
auth.php

'guards' => [
        
       [...]

        'applicant' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'applicants',
        ],
      ],

'providers' => [
        
        [...]

        'applicants' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\Applicant::class,
        ],
      ],
```

```
registerController.php

public function showApplicantRegisterForm()
    {
        return view('auth.register', ['url' => 'applicant']);
    }


    protected function createApplicant(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validator($request->all())->validate();
        $applicant = Applicant::create([
            'name' => $request['name'],
            'email' => $request['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($request['password']),
        ]);
        return redirect()->intended('login/applicant');
    }
```

```
routes.php

Route::get('/login/applicant', 'Auth\LoginController@showApplicantLoginForm');
Route::get('/register/applicant', 'Auth\RegisterController@showApplicantRegisterForm');


Route::post('/login/applicant', 'Auth\LoginController@applicantLogin');
Route::post('/register/applicant', 'Auth\RegisterController@createApplicant');

Route::view('/applicant', 'applicant');
```

Comment: Just to clarify: Are you looking for a way, that a new user that registers can be an Employer and Applicant at the same time?

Comment: No it can only be either an Applicant or Employer. @wschopohl

Comment: So what doesn't work as expected? Where exactly to you have problems?

Comment: When each Applicant or Employers registers, i want to associate each of them with their own Profile model knowing that each Profile model has its own unique fields. That was my questions.

Comment: and what have you attempted to do with this `Profile` model?

Comment: You don't need two types of authentication for different roles. Just use the default user table and add a role column for each user.

Comment: @lagbox I just have posted an answer.

Comment: @Syazany Maybe, this approach i find it a little easy to accomplish what i want to do, which is separting each user with their own tables and associations.

Answer (score 1):

Finally got it working, providing `ApplicantsProfile` fields in `auth/registerController` and associate it to an applicant.

Instead of using one register view, I have added a custom register view for applicants. I'm sure there's another work around to resolve duplicate code using conditions in one view. but so far this is what's working for me.

```
public function showApplicantRegisterForm()
    {
        return view('auth.applicant_register', ['url' => 'applicant']);
    }

protected function createApplicant(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validator($request->all())->validate();
        $applicant = Applicant::create([
            'name' => $request['name'],
            'email' => $request['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($request['password']),
        ]);



        ApplicantsProfile::create([
            'applicant_id' => $applicant->id,
            'job_title' => $request['job_title'],
        ]);
        return redirect()->intended('login/applicant');
    }
```

```
applicant_register.blade.php

@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">{{ isset($url) ? ucwords($url) : ""}} {{ __('Register') }}</div>

                <div class="card-body">
                @isset($url)
                        <form method="POST" action='{{ url("register/$url") }}' aria-label="{{ __('Register') }}">
                        @else
                        <form method="POST" action="{{ route('register') }}" aria-label="{{ __('Register') }}">
                        @endisset
                        @csrf

                        [...]

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="job_title" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('JobTitle') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="job_title" type="text" class="form-control @error('job_title') is-invalid @enderror" name="job_title" value="{{ old('job_title') }}" required autocomplete="job_title" autofocus>

                                @error('job_title')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        [...]

                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```